# Show cordinates usind cv2.findcontours

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv, computer-vision, coordinates

I know when we use the function cv2.findcountors, the variable Contours receive a numpy array of (x,y) coordinates of boundary points of the object. I need to "import" this coordinates and using cv2.putText show in my video, but i don't have ideia how to do this.
Someone can explain how i do this?

Comment: do you want to show all the coordinates or a subset?

Comment: My ideia is show only the coordinates of found objects.
It's ok if be able print the coordenates on terminal.

Comment: you have to index the array from the variable containing the contours